# Declare new function inside a class using a template

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm still learning about templates. I'm not sure whether you can declare/(automatically define) a function inside a class (method) using a template. That is, I have a function template defined like this, for example:

```
template<typename T>
T getT() {
    T result;
    return result;
}
```

And a class, where I want the "new function" to be created, based on the template, like this:

```
class World{
public:
    World();
    ~World();
    getT<int>; //"Magically" create new function from the template (return type 'int')

}
```

What I actually want is to have only a method with the specific given type in World. That means when I want to "magically" create a method based on the template, I want to sort of copy-paste the template function into the class but with the given type.

For example:

```
class World{
public:
    World();
    ~World();

    //The magically created function with T equal to int
    int getT(){
        int result;
        return result;
    }

}
```

Then of course I expect to be able to call the function:

```
int main(){
    World world; //Create world object
    world.getT<int>; //Call the function
    return 0;
}
```

Even though here I say I would call it with `getT<int>`, it could be only `getT()` (if it is a perfect copy-paste of the template function).

Comment: Your `getT` returns a reference to a local variable, which is a no-no.

Comment: There are many ways to implement something like that (using traits, CRTP, Mixins ...). But the choice depends on where you want to put the complexity and/or the specialisation. Can you be more specific ?

Comment: @MichaelDoubez I literally just want to "copy-paste" the template function into the class but with desired type. That's it. I said I would call it by world.getT<int>, but being able to call it by getT() would be even better.

Comment: @Nyck The only doable copy paste is by using macro (sic). Rule of thumb it to put as much code as possible in a free function template and use a macro to define code that call it (in your case `#define DEFINE_GET_T(T) T getT(){return ::getT<T>(); }`) and then `DEFINE_GET_T(int)` in the class. Otherwise, for such a simple/general case, the solution of inheriting a helper is enough (R Sahu answer). Another solution (that I prefer it to keep it as free function). I'll post and answer about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
getT<int>; //"Magically" create new function from the template (return type 'int')
```

I don't think that will work.

It appears as though you would like to be able to use templates like macro expansion. Unfortunately, they are very different things and templates don't work like macro expansion.

However, you can use something like the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct GetHelper
{
   T get()
   {
      return T{};
   }
};


class World : private GetHelper<int>,
              private GetHelper<double>
{
   public:
      World() {}
      ~World() {}
      template <typename T>
         get()
         {
            return static_cast<GetHelper<T>*>(this)->get();
         }

};
```

Now you can use:

```
World w;
int a = w.get<int>();
double b = w.get<double>();
```

---

You may also hide `GetHelper` as a `private` type of `World` as:

```
class World 
{
   private:
      template<typename T>
         struct GetHelper
         {
            T get()
            {
               return T{};
            }
         };

      struct Data : GetHelper<int>,
                    GetHelper<double>{};

      Data data;

   public:
      World() {}
      ~World() {}
      template <typename T>
         get()
         {
            return static_cast<GetHelper<T>*>(&data)->get();
         }

};
```

Comment: I am sure I misunderstood, but why won't a template method in a class work? Why can't one have a simple `template <typename T> T getT() { return T{};}` method inside the class World? Here is a simple example http://cpp.sh/8hmeq

Comment: @cplusplusrat, It will absolutely work. What I was saying is `get<int>();` as a member function won't work. I think the OP thinks that templates can be used like macro expansion.

Comment: Right, re-read the post. Yes, some sort of template specialization would be required to invoke specific method based on template parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Be carfull

```cpp
template<typename T>
T& getT() {
    T result;
    return result;
}
```

Will return a reference to a temporary. Please do

```cpp
template<typename T>
T getT() {
    T result;
    return result;
}
```

without "&"

And if it's just for get a specific member, you can use std::tuple.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get

Comment: No need to add an answer to tell me that. But thank you, I had seen @1201ProgramAlarm 's comment, but forgot about it. Will edit.

Comment: my bad didn't see @1201ProgramAlarm 's comment